# iterate xml array request one by one before hitting webserviceconsumer

Tags: xml, mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

The complete request is :

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
<balanceInquiry>
    <request>
        <amount>
            <amount>1</amount>
            <currency>USD</currency>
        </amount>
    </request>
    <request>
        <amount>
            <amount>2</amount>
            <currency>USD</currency>
        </amount>
     </request>
     <request>
        <amount>
            <amount>3</amount>
            <currency>USD</currency>
        </amount>
      </request>
</balanceInquiry>
```

Before hitting to webconsumer it should be :

```
<balanceInquiry>
    <request>
        <amount>
            <amount>1</amount>
            <currency></currency>
        </amount>
    </request>
</balanceInquiry>
```

And then put response for 1 then again go for 2 and so on.

I am using a for each component like

```
<foreach collection="#[payload.balanceInquiry]" doc:name="For Each">
    <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" operation="balanceInquiry" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
</foreach>
```

But its not working. Is there any other component available to perform the task or am I doing it wrong. Please suggest.

Comment: Hi @Rjakhmola, did you deserialise it into a pojo? The foreach only accepts collections.

Comment: No, I didnt the problem is every time I send the xml request to HTTP it becomes bufferstream. Now I am not able to convert it to any other format

Comment: I see, use a Byte array to Object (add expected class name in the return class box) or a Byte array to String so you will be able to transform those. Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [splitter](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/splitter-flow-control-reference) to split your `xml` and then `dom to xml transformer` before making a web service call

```
<splitter expression="#[xpath3('//balanceInquiry/request',payload,'NODESET')]"/>        
<mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
```

Comment: but my output of each request decides whether to go for the next request or not. because if the first request is a success then i will go for second if it fails then I have to revert back.

Comment: exit out of `foreach` loop for that

Comment: Also its throws exception ERROR 2016-03-15 08:21:23,778 [[pet_order_payment15].HTTP_Listener_Configuration2.worker.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: Caught exception in Exception Strategy: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getPayloadAsBytes(), use getPayload(DataType.BYTE_ARRAY_DATA_TYPE)
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getPayloadAsBytes(), use getPayload(DataType.BYTE_ARRAY_DATA_TYPE)

Comment: that's how payload is being accessed... can't comment without looking at your config

Comment: any suggestion on how to put multiple responses of the webservice as a payload. is there any way I could append a response with previous response?

Comment: That's really another question not a follow-up. Open an another question and accept this one if it answered you